# Relating two dimension in SSAS cube

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I have two dimension, say "Dimension1" and "Dimension2"
These two dimension should be related, like Dimension1 can have one or more records in Dimension2.

To relate, I have an intermediate table, say "Dimension12"

Sample values are as below.

Dimension1

```
Column 1
A
B
C
```

Dimension2

```
Column2
X
Y
Z
```

Dimension12

```
Column1 Column2
A       X
A       Y
B       X
C       Y
C       Z
```

In DSV I related these 2 tables using “Dimension12” table. Created two new dimension, Dimension1 and Dimension2. Deployed and processed cube.

Now when I query, I used Column1 from Dimension1 and Column2 from Dimension2, this is not giving me required result, I want to see X and Y under A , instead it gives me all like X, Y, Z under A and X, Y, Z under B and X, Y, Z under C. Relational between dimension is not happening. I do not want them to relate through facts.

Can you please help what I am missing here. Or is it possible to do such.

Comment: I wonder why you haven't build a hierarchy with 2 levels under a single dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with Dimension12 .

It should be generated using **full outer join** if (there is any join key .)

Else it should be created as **cross join** of Dimension1 and Dimension 2  in case there is no relation .

you Dimension12  should have below data

```
Column1  Column2
A        x
B        x
C        x
A        y
B        y
C        y
```

Edit after comment.

In case we donot have relation in Dimension1 and Dimension2

**step 1** >  Create a table Dimension12

```
   Create  table Dimension12 
( id int identity (1,1),-- as i would required a surrogate key for referencing in fact.

Column1 varchar(50),

Column2 varchar(50))


    insert into Dimension12 (Column1,Column2)
     select d1.Column1,d2.Column2 from Dimension1 d1,Dimension2 d2
```

**step 2>** One time populate data

```
insert into Dimension12 (Column1,Column2)
select d1.Column1,d2.Column2 from Dimension1 d1,Dimension2 d2
```

**step 3** > make a Updateinsert ETL to populate Dimension12  tbale.

**step 4** > use Dimension12 (table or view on top of this table )in DSV.

Now you are good to go..

Comment: Dimension12 does have the data as you said. But I didnt what you were saying about full outer join, DSV does have relationship, Primary "Dimension1" Foreign "Dimension12" and Primary "Dimension2" Foreign "Dimension12"

Comment: in case if you do not have any relation ship in Dimension1  and Dimension1  in that case cross join /CARTESIAN JOIN ie  select d1.Column1,d2.Column2 from Dimension1 d1,Dimension2 d2.. i  will be adding more detail in answer ...

Comment: Thanks, but i m not sure how it solves my problem. I do not want catersian product data. Dimension12 already has relation between dimension 1 and dimension2, if in that the case I dont see why i need to insert catesian product again. Probably I didnt get. Problem is i modeled it and still relation is not happening. I am using dimension12 only to relate. If I use Colum1 from Dimension1 and Column2 from Dimension2 then it should shows the relationship and this is not happening.

Comment: I have mentioned the logic in answer and this should be the part of your ETL you requires  surrogate key

Comment: are u saying that I would need a key to relate to fact, if so NO, i do not want to relate this to fact at all. I just want to relate between dimension with NO relation to fact.. will that be possible?

Comment: Then what you be achieve  doing this  . you can try using Dimension uses tab and use many to many relationship ....

Comment: This still not resolved, as suggested I related through fact, but still it doesnt work as expected. Did Many Many relationship as well.. Not sure the exact problem.. can someone if I need to edit the question or post a new one